# Unir 3 Bases de datos en SQL

Tags: sql-server

Tengo 3 Bases de datos distintas con las mismas columnas y datos distintos, donde seguro 100% una columna (llamada telefono) esta completa en todos y algunas filas se repiten en las otras 3 bases de datos.

Las 3 bases de datos cuentan con columna fecha, telefono, origen, final, pago, sitio actual y fechadecambio. Y cada base de datos se llama Virginia, Yago y Maria

Mi consulta es la siguiente:

¿Como podría unificar las 3 bases de datos en una sola mediante SQL?

Probe y no funciono

```
Select [Telefono] from [dbo].[Virginia]
Select [Telefono] from [dbo].[Yago]
Select [Telefono] from [dbo].[Maria]

JOIN Telefono AS h 
ON h.Virginia = h.Yago
```

Comment: 3 bases de datos o tres tablas de una misma Base de Datos!!!??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para "unir" tablas dispones del [`UNION`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-union-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) y el [`UNION ALL`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-union-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
Select [Telefono] from [dbo].[Virginia]
union
Select [Telefono] from [dbo].[Yago]
union
Select [Telefono] from [dbo].[Maria]
```

El `union` no replica filas repetidas, en este ejemplo si en dos tablas tuvieras el mismo `[Telefono]` la consulta te retornaría uno solo, `UNION ALL` por el contrario te retornaría las repeticiones. Es obvio, pero importante aclarar que esto funciona adecuadamente si las estructuras de cada consulta son similares en cantidad de columnas, más especifícamnete:

- El número de columnas y el orden es el mismo en todas las consultas
- Los tipos de datos de cada columna son compatibles

Comment: Muchas gracias Patricio, pero mi duda es como hacer para juntarlas y que además me salgan las demás columnas. Cambié [Telefono] por * y me funciono. Mil gracias